Library to do crc32c hashing in React Native/Expo-go for GCS data integrity check?
I am sending some data from my react native app to store it on GCS bucket using signed url.
However, I don't want to risk writing my own implementation for crc32c hashing and making mistake. Is there a recommended library for doing this in react native? I am able to find recommended libraries here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags#crc32c
but none of them are on pure JS/Typescript.
Note that I am looking for CRC32C implementation and not CRC32, as this is what is supported by GCS
Thanks

Can you have a look at these links: liink1 & link2.

I did try that one but it's giving me incorrect value. The values on reflected on GCS are different from the one I am getting using this library.
